# Blinking TreeView after programatically selected node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a problem with flickering `TreeView`. I want first node to be selected after creation of `TreeView`.

```
tv.SelectedNode = tv.Nodes[0];
```

This set this, but also first click on any node in program makes `TreeView` blink, and after that everything is fine and after next clicks nothing is flickering. 
I use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` on `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, and in fact it works, but only after that first click. Without programmatically selecting first node as selected it works well. I have no idea, what makes `TreeView` blink.

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Comment: Most likely some event handler. double check all the event hadlers

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. In what event handler you place this `tv.SelectedNode = tv.Nodes[0];`?

Comment: While i proceed from one screen to another (by clicking Next) I run method which loads DataSet from file and then creates TreeView where TreeNodes are columns of Table in this DataSet. At the end of this method, after creating TreeView and all his Nodes I set selected Node.

Comment: @soshman It looks like that your `TreeView` is created and the node is selected while it's invisible?

Comment: @KingKing That's right. I set focus and selecting the node after proceeding to the screen and there's no flickering now. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid flickering using the TreeView descendant with double-buffered painting enabled:

```
class DoubleBufferedTreeView : TreeView {
    public MyTreeView() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }
}
```